# Highcharts chart categories not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**EDIT:** Here's a fiddle, thanks to JordanD for getting it displaying something:
jsfiddle.net

**EDIT(2):** From what I can tell, this is how a single series chart displays.  Adding a second series (a second element in the data array) causes the chart to display as I expected it to, but with one series, it is basically centered instead of justified.  Therefore, it's not 'broken', it just doesn't behave as I expected it to.

The data series is in the form of an array of objects in the form of:

```
name: 'string'
data: ['array', 'of', 'data']
```

As can be seen in the image, my x-axis categories are displaying as a string. It's being set as

```
categories: dates
```

Where dates is an array with an array of dates in the first index.  It appears that the only thing displaying in the categories is the first element of the array.  Even if I try

```
categories: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

the only thing that will show is 'this'.

[image: Borked highchart]

and here is the console log to accompany it with a small sample of the data:
[image: console log]

and here is the call to instantiate the chart:

```
 $("#chart").highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'report for ' + result[0].Name
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: date
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title:
                        {
                            text: 'Number'
                        }                            
                    },
                    series: dataSeries
                });
```

What I'm trying to get is for the x-axis labels (and the columns themselves) to be spaced out to take up the full width of the chart.

[image]

Comment: Why can you include sample pictures and pieces of code but not a fiddle?

Comment: Because a fiddle would require data.  This data is not available to the public.  The server is not accessible out of my network.

Comment: considering your data is not what has a problem, make up numbers for the graph and use the array of dates?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2km6/1/ here, add this to your question

Comment: Thanks, I added it. So... it's displaying correctly with static data.  Is it just not meant to be able to handle dynamically loaded data?  I copy/pasted a highcharts demo onto the same page, and it displays correctly, and I pretty much copied the structure for my own.

Comment: it could very well be the way in which your data is formatted.

Comment: Is it possible to just tie the category to the series name?  I tried leaving 'categories' unset, and just got a zero.

Comment: For getting the date, I cobbled together this: new Date(parseInt(value.Date.replace('/Date(', '')))

Comment: So how does it work now? You said you are using an arraylist and all of the dates are in the first index of that arraylist? maybe the arraylist causes a problem with highcharts

Comment: Yes, currently I have it set up the same way as the fiddle.  An array of objects with name/data attributes.  So like { name: date, data: [500] }.  This pushed into the array, the series is read correctly, it's just not rendering it correctly (the whitespace on either side and the categories not being synced up).  It appears that it's only reading the first element of the array for the categories, and no clue what's going on with the series data to not be working.  The fiddle works just fine with a similar setup.

Comment: If I were to just point it at an array of dates, it will only bind to the first element of that array.  If it were possible to just bind the name of the series to the categories, that would work as well I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 9 series and each point have the same x, so each serie starts on the same tick and you have result which you have.

Solutions:

- use one serie and set up a color for each point
- use [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) for each serie
- set data as pairs [x,y] but xAxis should be [category type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type).

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong here but I've tried the following without success: (1) dataSeries.push({ name: targetDate.toString(), data: [count], pointStart: targetDate }); (2) dataSeries.push({ name: targetDate.toString(), data: [x, count] });  I've not tried the one series thing.  I thought doing a series: dataSeries, and pushing all of the series into the dataSeries array would work... unless I can do the "addSeries" call before I instantiate the chart.

Comment: Replicate your example on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly an easy fix might be to add a data [type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) to your axis.

`type : 'datetime'`

```
 $("#chart").highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'report for ' + result[0].Name
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: date,
                    type : 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title:
                    {
                        text: 'Number'
                    }                            
                },
                series: dataSeries
            });
```

Comment: That didn't appear to do anything.  But with datetime, would that automatically parse the json '/Date(52982988bu99849)/' into a usable date format?

Comment: @Nick I am not entirely sure, I would test it using settings like highcharts gives in their fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime/